# Prove that $e$ is irrational using this result

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, exponential-function, irrational-numbers

I have to prove that $e$ is irrational using this result

$1/e = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$

and getting the estimation for the partial sums $0 < 1/e - s_{2k-1} < \frac{1}{(2k)!}$

I tried, but I obtain $0 < 1/e + \frac{1}{(2k-1)!} = \frac{1}{(2k)!} < 1$, and I don't think it's good

Comment: $1/e-s_{2k-1}=\sum_{n=2k}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}=\frac{1}{(2k)!}+(\frac{1}{(2k+2)!}-\frac{1}{(2k+1)!})+\cdots$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you know that $0<1/e-s_{2k-1}<\frac{1}{(2k)!}$,

suppose that $e=\frac{p}{q}$ for integers $p,q$ and $p\neq 0$ ($e\neq 0$ obviously). From above

$$
0<\frac{(2k)!}{e}-m_k<1
$$

where $m_k=(2k)!s_{2k-1}$ is an **integer**. Since this is true for all $k$, we can pick some $k$ such that $2k\ge |p|$ so that $\frac{(2k)!}{e}=\frac{q(2k)!}{p}$ is also an integer.

But this is a contradiction, since then $\frac{(2k)!}{e}-m_k$ is an integer between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Thank you, I have only one doubt... How can I say that $m_k$ is for sure an integer?

Comment: @brt22 write out terms in $s_{2k-1}$, each term is of the form $\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}$ where $n\le 2k-1$. So when you multiply by $(2k)!$ the denominator cancels out: $(2k)! \times \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}=(-1)^n \cdot (n+1)\cdots 2k$ which is an integer

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $e=\frac{p}{q}$ with $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ and $\gcd(p,q)=1$. We have
$$ \frac{q}{p}=\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!} = \sum_{k=0}^{p}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}+\sum_{k>p}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!} $$
from which
$$ q(p-1)! = \underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^{p}(-1)^k\frac{p!}{k!}}_{\in\mathbb{Z}}+\underbrace{\sum_{k>p}\frac{(-1)^k p!}{k!}}_{\text{absolute value }\in(0,1)} $$
leading to a contradiction.

Comment: Can we omit $\gcd(p,q)=1$?

Comment: @MyGlasses: oh, yes, that is not really crucial.

Comment: Sorry what does gcd(p,q) = 1 mean?

Comment: @brt22: $\gcd$ stands for **g**reatest **c**ommon **d**ivisor.